# How to position div with text on an image and scale both

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, styled-components

Trying to place a `div` with an image and text in between auto generated `div`s.

**Codesandbox:**  https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-fe1l6

My page structure:

```
    <div class=chapter>
      <div class=heading>Heading 1</div>
      <div class=bodyText>Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. </div>
    </div>
    <div class=chapter>
      <div>Heading 2</div>
      <div class=bodyText>Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2.</div>
    </div>
    <div class=chapter>
      <div class=imageContainer>
        <img class=image src="..." ></img>
        <div class=imageQuote>"This is some quote. Lot of text is here" - Author</div>
      </div>
      <div>Heading 3</div>
    <div class=bodyText>Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chapter{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.heading {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.bodyText {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.imageContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;

}
.image {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;

}
.imageQoute {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 168px;
  width: 228px;
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 15.5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Problem**: The imageQuote div should float on middle right hand side of the img with a specific width which should scale (When screen sizes increases or decreases the img and 'imageQuote' div should also increase or decrease) but the position of the 'imageQoute' div should always be same (on middle right of the img).

**Question:** How to position a div on top of an image and auto scale while not losing position.

**Codesandbox:**  https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-fe1l6

Comment: A `codesandbox` where you reproduce it would be of great help

Comment: @aquinq Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-fe1l6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.larger-text {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.imageContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.imageContainer > * {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Another simple example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class=chapter>
      <div class=heading>Heading 1</div>
      <div class=bodyText>Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. </div>
    </div>
    <div class=chapter>
      <div>Heading 2</div>
      <div class=bodyText>Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2.</div>
    </div>
    <div class=chapter>
      <div class=imageContainer>
        <img class=image src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" ></img>
        <div class=imageQuote>"This is some quote. Lot of text is here" - Author</div>
      </div>
      <div>Heading 3</div>
    <div class=bodyText>Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Text is positioned on the middle right of the image, however i'm not sure what you meant for the image width. Hope this is what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the image and `div` to the same height, then center the text with flexbox:

```css
.larger-text {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.imageQuote {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Another simple example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class=chapter>
    <div class=heading>Heading 1</div>
    <div class=bodyText>Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. Chapter body 1. </div>
  </div>
  <div class=chapter>
    <div>Heading 2</div>
    <div class=bodyText>Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2. Chapter body 2.</div>
  </div>
  <div class=chapter>
    <div class=imageContainer>
      <img class=image src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"></img>
      <div class=imageQuote>"This is some quote. Lot of text is here" - Author</div>
    </div>
    <div>Heading 3</div>
    <div class=bodyText>Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3. Chapter body 3</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is that how you mean?

Comment: No I am afraid. The imageQuote `div` should float on middle right hand side of the `img` with a specific `width` which should scale (When screen sizes increases or decreases the `img` and 'imageQuote' `div` should also increase or decrease) but the position of the 'imageQoute' `div` should always be same (on middle right of the `img`)